# Backbone collection's models disapear after parse

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I have this model and a collection for it:

```
app.models.Result= Backbone.Model.extend({

    idAttribute: 'uid',

    initialize: function () {
        this.set('name', this.get('name').replace(' ', '').substring(0, 20));
    },

});

app.models.ResultList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: app.models.Result,
    url: 'http://localhost/stuff',

    parse: function (response, options) {
        this.add(response.data);
        console.log(this);
        return response.data;
    },

});
```

Then I use it in my view's `initialize()` function like this:

```
var that = this;
this.collection = new app.models.SearchList();
this.collection.fetch({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function () {
        console.log(that.collection);
        that.collection.each(function (resultModel) {
            console.log('ok');
        });
    }
});
```

With this code I almost get what I want, but when I look at the second `log()` I can see that the `name` property is the same as it was in the fetched JSON.

[image: First try's logs]

My guess is because I simply returned the `response.data`, so I modified it to `this`. In this case I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

So I commented out that line. Now I can see that all the models are gone. The array has only one model in it but that is not one from the JSON.

[image: Second try's logs]

What happend with my beloved models? Where are they? Should I save them somehow? At the first log `this` pointed to the correct full collection, so why doesn't returning `this` gives me the same correct collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were correct when you were returning `response.data` from `Collection.parse`.  To quote [the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse):

> The function is passed the raw response object, and should return the array of model attributes to be added to the collection

I think your problem is that you're calling `this.add` from within `Collection.parse` - you don't need to do this, as the function that calls `Collection.parse` will deal with that for you.

I think what is happening when you do this is that the models are added when you call `add`, but then the Collection calls `Collection.set` - which causes all of the name values that you've modified to be replaced with the server versions.

To respond to your comment: `Collection.set` is called as part of `Collection.fetch` - that is just the way Backbone works by default (though you can have it call `Collection.reset` if you wish, by passing in an option).  The easiest way to solve your problem would just be to remove the `Collection.add` call from your `parse` function - that way `Collection.set` will act as you expect.

The `initialize` function is just called on initialization of a model.  If you want to change properties of models when they are first created that is one place to do it.  However, you're creating the model by calling `this.add`, and then updating that data by returning data from `parse` - which causes the initialize changes to be overwritten.

Another way to do it would be to update your `parse` function to convert the data as needed, and then return that.

Alternatively you could override the set function in your Model to transform the data it is passed if the value being set is `name`

Comment: Thank for your response. I understand what are you talking about, but why does the `Collection.set` is called? What is more important: How can I solve the problem? How can I apply my changes to the `name` property in the model? I thought that the initialization function is the proper way. What is the purpose of the initialization if `set` overwrites what I have done there?

Comment: @totymedli I've added a bit more detail with specific instructions on what to do.  To put it simply: don't call `this.add` in `parse`

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I totally understand the whole procedure and the suggestions you gave me made the code work like a charm! Thank you again.